# Response keeps executing after success in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, response

I have a Parent and Child components. The child is a map that is centered on specific coordinates. On form submit, I'm updating the map coordinates in the child component by passing props (coordinates) from the Parent. The coordinates are geocoded from an address string entered by the user.

Everything works fine, except that the response, although successfull, loops infinitely. After a minute this just crashes my browser.

How should I stop the response from updating every second?

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

class MapContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({centerMap: {
            lat: nextProps.lat,
            lng: nextProps.lng
        }})
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <Map center={this.props.centerMap} zoom={13} >
            <TileLayer
            attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
          </Map>
        );
    }
}

class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userCoords: {
                lat: 91.93373,
                lng: -81.4280
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        let data = this.props.data;

        // set Google Maps Geocoding API for purposes of quota management. Its optional but recommended.
        Geocode.setApiKey("MY_API_KEY");

        // Get latidude & longitude from address.
        Geocode.fromAddress(data.location).then(
          response => {
              const coords = response.results[0].geometry.location;

              this.setState({
                  userCoords: {
                      lat: coords.lat,
                      lng: coords.lng
                  }
              })
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
          }
        );

        return (
            <main className="main-card">
                <div className="main-card--header-bg">
                    <MapContainer centerMap={this.state.userCoords}/>
                </div>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: On the response you are setting a new state.
This will trigger a rerender, hence the render() method will be called again.
This will result in another request with a successfull response and so on.
Do not set new state in the render method

Comment: So either place the request in componentDidMount if you only need it once (on the first render) or you have to make some way of checking if you should fetch a new location. I do not see any usecase where you need to refresh it on each render

Comment: I've put it outside of the render, and used a function called 'handleGeocoding' to call the geocoder when the component gets updates. Still I get an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move

`Geocode.setApiKey("MY_API_KEY");` to constructor or global.

Then create a method say

```
fetchCoords(location) {
  Geocode.fromAddress(location).then(
          response => {
              const coords = response.results[0].geometry.location;

              this.setState({
                  userCoords: {
                      lat: coords.lat,
                      lng: coords.lng
                  }
              })
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
          }
        );

}
```

Now in Wrapper component write componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate

```
componentDidMount() {
 let data = this.props.data;
 this.fetchCoords(data.location);  
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.data != prevProps.data) {
    let data = this.props.data;
    this.fetchCoords(data.location); 
  }
}
```

componentDidMount will fetch coordinates and set it in the state, triggering a rerender. So componentDidUpdate will be called as props have not changed it won't call fetchCoords again. Now if props.data changes componentDidUpdate will be invoked this time props will be new and new fetch will be initiated.

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thanks for the detailed info and the excellent answer!